# datatables con php, jquery y postgresql

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql, datatables

Buen día, he estado trabajando sin ningún problema con datatables, php y mysql, pero al intentar hacer uso del plugin con Postgresql no ha funcionado, no se si requiere alguna configuración adicional. de antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda o recomendación.

Si alguien tiene un enlace donde se muestren ejemplos de datatables y postgres estaria muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco tuve la misma problemática pero por suerte para ambos pude resolverla, a continuación te dejo todo lo que he hecho para trabajar con bases de datos en postgres;

Personalmente utilizo WAMP server y manejo la conexion con PDO y sus metodos;

Lo primero es abrir el archivo `php.ini` y dentro del archivo buscar la línea `“extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll”` la cual tendrá un punto y coma delante `(;)`, se quita esto y se reinicia el `wamp`. Esto para usar PDO con postgres

Para realizar la conexion puedes tomar de ejemplo el siguiente codigo;

archivo:`dbconfig_postgres.php`

```
<?php

$host='127.0.0.1';
$db = 'mi_base_datos';
$username = 'postgres';
$password = '1706';

?>
```

archivo: `conexion_postgres.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig_postgres.php';
    $dsn = "pgsql:host=$host;port=5432;dbname=$db;user=$username;password=$password";

try{
    $base_postgres = new PDO($dsn);
    $base_postgres->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Conexion correcta PostGres";

}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "BD fuera de servicio";
}
?>
```

configurada ya la conexion solo queda realizar consultas, te dejo una de ejemplo;

```
    include('conexion_postgres.php');
    $registros=$base_postgres->prepare('Select id,nombre,correo  From "mi_esquema"."mi_tabla"');                

    $registros->execute(array());
    //Por si quieres saber cuantos registros arrojo la consulta
    $registros = $registros_niscap->rowCount();

    $registros = $registros->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
```

Suponiendo que sabes utilizar PDO ya lo demás es acceder mediante un array indexado o con un foreach.

De cualquier forma cualquier pregunta puedo continuar editando la respuesta para agregarte lo que necesites.

Comment: vale gracias, voy a iniciar modificación de la codificación pues no estaba usando PDO.